# Can I use Lichess to store my over-the-board games?

Tags: database, lichess

I recently got back into playing long games over the board, and I'd like to have some kind of database of my played games. This database would need to include searchable metadata including game date and opponent name and ELO. I already use Lichess to analyse my games.

Does Lichess have this capability? If not, does any other popular open-source tool?

Comment: To directly answer your question: no, there currently is no way for lichess to create a database of just your games in a collection of studies. They do give you a way to explore your games played on the website, but it is not very customizable and does not include any imported games.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll You can actually import and analyze games at their cost, even if you have *not* played them on their website.

Comment: @Hauptideal Yes but that's not the question. My point is that those games will not appear in your opening explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SCID is a free chess database application (that may be used as a ChessBase "alternative") that you can use to save your games, allowing metadata searches.

You could continue to analyse your games on lichess (even though you could of course also do it in SCID directly) in a study, export the study as PGN and import it to SCID to have it as a searchable database.

Comment: 1.5 years later I just want to say that SCID was exactly what I needed, with my game database in Google Drive. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Beside SCID, there's also a good application called chessis, where you can store your Over The Board games. You can also analyze your game. I hope that I was beneficial to you.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for open-source alternatives though. I could have been clearer in my question